# Including time as an explicit variable in constraint in a Pyomo Model

Tags: matlab, pyomo

I am using PyOMO to model a semi-batch reaction.

Consider an ODE system that describes a semi-batch reactor where one of the reactants is fed at a given volume flow for *t1* units of time, the reaction goes on until *t <sub>end</sub>*,  and  obviously *t1* < *t <sub>end</sub>*.

To specify the stop in the flow, I can either use a conditional rule (assume *t1* = 3.5*60):

```
def _vol_flow_in_schedule(mod,t):
 if t<=3.5*60:
  return mod.vol_flow_in[t] == (12.3/1000)/(3.5*60)
 else:
  return mod.vol_flow_in[t] == 0
m1.vol_flow_in_schedule = Constraint(m1.time,rule=_vol_flow_in_schedule)
```

which will create a discontinuity (and then my model does not converge). What I want to do is use a sigmoidal function that will transition the flow to zero without a discontinuity.

To implement the sigmoidal though I need to refer to the time variable itself.

The below MATLAB code gives me the result I want:

```
t=[0:1:500];
acc=2;  %Acceleration parameter, higher values yields sharper change.
time_of_step=3.5*60;
init_value = (12.3/1000)/(3.5*60);
end_value = 0;
sigmoidal=(init_value+(end_value-init_value)/2)...
          +((end_value-init_value)/2)*atan((t-time_of_step)*acc)/atan(max(t));
```

This implementation however  needs the time variable explicitly in the function. How can I access the time variable inside the PyOMO rule? I tried the below, but I get an " Cannot treat the scalar component 't_of_step' as an array" error:

```
m1.init_value = Param(initialize = (12.3/1000)/(3.5*60))
m1.end_value  = Param(initialize = 0)
m1.t_of_step  = Param(initialize = 210)
m1.acc        = Param(initialize = 5)
.
.

def _vol_flow_sigmoidal (mod,t):
 return mod.vol_flow_in[t] == (mod.init_value+(mod.end_value-mod.init_value)/2)+((mod.end_value-mod.init_value)/2)*atan((t-mod.t_of_step)*mod.acc)/atan(1500)
m1.vol_flow_sigmoidal = Constraint(m1.time,rule=_vol_flow_sigmoidal)
```

Hopefully I've described clearlyt what I am after. Any hints are most welcome,

Thanks!
*Sal*

Answer (score 1):

How are you declaring the `m1.time` index?

My guess is that you are using a NumPy array to initialize the `m1.time` index.  There is a known problem in Pyomo (see [Issue #31](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/31)) where the NumPy operator overloading and the Pyomo operator overloading end up fighting with each other (basically, NumPy gets fooled into thinking Pyomo scalars are actually indexed and attempts to treat them like arrays).

I was able to reproduce the error with the following complete example:

```
# pyomo 4.4.1
from pyomo.environ import *                                                     
import numpy as np                                                              

m1 = ConcreteModel()                                                            
m1.time = Set(initialize=np.array([0,100,200,300,400,500]))                     
m1.vol_flow_in = Var(m1.time)                                                   

m1.init_value = Param(initialize = (12.3/1000)/(3.5*60))                        
m1.end_value  = Param(initialize = 0)                                           
m1.t_of_step  = Param(initialize = 210)                                         
m1.acc        = Param(initialize = 5)                                           

def _vol_flow_sigmoidal (mod,t):                                                
 return mod.vol_flow_in[t] == (mod.init_value+(mod.end_value-mod.init_value)/2)\
+((mod.end_value-mod.init_value)/2)*atan((t-mod.t_of_step)*mod.acc)/atan(1500)  
m1.vol_flow_sigmoidal = Constraint(m1.time,rule=_vol_flow_sigmoidal)
```

There are two alternatives that do work, both based on avoiding using NumPy arrays to initialize Pyomo Sets.  You can either completely avoid Numpy:

```
m1.time = Set(initialize=[0,100,200,300,400,500])
```

or explicitly cast the NumPy array to a list:

```
timeArray = np.array([0,100,200,300,400,500])
m1.time = Set(initialize=timeArray.tolist())
```

Finally, for completeness, two other notes:

1. This also applies to initializing `ContinuousSet` objects in `pyomo.dae`
2. You will see the same behavior even if you avoid the explicit Pyomo `Set` declaration.  That is, the following will also generate the error:

```python
m1.time = np.array([0,100,200,300,400,500])
# ...
m1.vol_flow_sigmoidal = Constraint(m1.time,rule=_vol_flow_sigmoidal)
```

This is because Pyomo will quietly create the Set object for you behind the scenes as `m1.vol_flow_sibmodial_index` and then use that Set to index the Constraint.

Comment: Thanks John, I delcare m1.time as a continuous set _m1.time=ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1500))- I am not using numpy

Comment: Then I am more confused.  With `m1.time = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,1500))`, I do not get any errors (I tested on both Pyomo 4.3.11388 and 4.4.1).  There are 2 things that could help diagnose things: 1) the full stack trace that Python spits out when it generates the error, and 2) a complete example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I can get you the complete file, email ?

Comment: Absolutely.  E-mail would be perfect.